# PS4 controller charging issues after battery replacement

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I replaced the battery on my PS4 controller, as it is the 1000mAh battery.
I bought 2200mAh for longer power and charges etc etc. Now my PS4 controller is charging all by itself with out the power supply cord, now this happened to my other one I replaced as well and now it’s completely dead and won’t charge through the top charger port but if I put it in a charging dock, which charges through the bottom, I can pick it up while it’s still connected to the charging dock and use it. But if I remove it? It goes DEAD!

I need help, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, while yes it is possible to "upgrade" your battery, it is ill-advised, because this kind of problem can be the result.

[This page](https://www.androidcentral.com/can-you-replace-ps4-controller-battery) has a more in depth explanation, however the short version is that if you do replace it, you need to understand several things:

1. The power of the battery can affect the functionality of the controller. It is designed to use the 1000mAh battery, so upgrading (or downgrading) it can cause it to not work as intended.
2. The connection on the controller can change based on the version of the controller. There are 2 versions: Made pre-2016, and post-2016. You can identify this by looking at the label on the back and finding the "MODEL" number. If it has a 1 in it, it's pre-2016, if it's got a 2 in it, it's post-2016.
3. Charging vs holding a charge are 2 different issues as well. If it doesn't charge it could be the charge port, or the connection to the battery itself.